# Convert Javascript/jQuery Query into XPath

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath

I'm trying to convert the following jQuery into XPath:

```
$(".change_language_div span.k-dropdown:nth-of-type(2)")
```

This is what I have but it is not working:

```
$x("//div[@class='change_language_div']/span[@class='k-dropdown'][1]")
```

The first part: `//div[@class='change_language_div']` is working but if I include the second part I get an empty array.

Comment: Please show the URL of the page you are searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$x("//div[@class='change_language_div']//span[2][@class='k-dropdown']")`.

Comment: I have edited my suggestion as I think in CSS `.change_language_div span` describes a descendant relationship so in XPath we need `//div//span`.